# Ruby on Rails protect_from_forgery, why not default behind the scenes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just starting learning Ruby/Rails, followed a few guides and videos. Basically, from what I gather the point of rails is to assume defaults, and hide them behind the scenes, and then when you want to change functionality you can.

When I create a new project, I noticed the line "protect_from_forgery" in my ApplicationController. Why is this created inside the file when I create a project in my IDE, and not kept default behind the scenes / in the superclass? Seems to be a bit anti-practice to what I've read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is that you need to know that csrf protection  is by default enabled everywhere out of the box.  It's just a way to make sure you're aware of it,  in case you need to disable it in certain cases.  If it were buried behind the scenes,  and you wanted to disable it for certain actions,  you'd have to go digging around and find out how csrf protection was enabled in the first place.  It's Rails saying 'LOOK THIS IS IMPORTANT, IF YOU WANT OTHER THAN THE DEFAULT BEHAVIOR, HERE IS WHERE YOU START!'